# I can't move my player in pygame, can you figure why?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a little game, and I came across a problem which I can't seem to figure out. The problem is that my sprite isn't moving after creating the game loop and the `if` statements with the `keyup`'s and what not. Can you guys figure it out and tell me why it's not working?

Here's my code so far:

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
windowWidth = 600
windowHeight = 400
windowSize = (600, 400)
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight), 0, 32)
display = pygame.Surface((300, 200))
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (225, 225, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
moveRight = False
moveLeft = False
moveSpeed = 6

level=   [['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
    ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
    ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
    ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
    ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','2','2','2','2','2','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
    ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
    ['2','2','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','2','2'],
    ['1','1','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','0','0','2','2','2','1','1'],
    ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','0','0','1','1','1','1','1'],
    ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','0','0','1','1','1','1','1'],
    ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','0','0','1','1','1','1','1'],
    ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','0','0','1','1','1','1','1'],
    ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','0','0','1','1','1','1','1']]

grass = pygame.image.load('grass.png')
dirt = pygame.image.load('dirt.png')
player = pygame.image.load('player.png').convert()
playerRect = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 5, 13)
player.set_colorkey((255,255,255))

while True:
    display.fill((214, 42, 78))
    #display.blit(player,(playerRect.x,playerRect.y))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                moveRight = True
            if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                moveLeft = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                moveRight = False
            if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                moveLeft = False
    display.blit(player,(playerRect.x,playerRect.y))



    playerMovement = [0, 0]
    if moveRight == True:
        playerMovement[0] += 2
    if moveLeft == True:
        playerMovement[0] -= 2


    tileRect = []
    y = 0
    for row in level:
        x = 0
        for col in row:
            if col == '2':
                display.blit(grass, (x*16, y*16))
            if col == '1':
                display.blit(dirt, (x*16, y*16))
            if col != '0':
                tileRect.append(pygame.Rect(x*16,y*16,16,16))
            x += 1
        y += 1


    #pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, black, player)
    windowSurface.blit(pygame.transform.scale(display, windowSize),(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Where is the sprite? And why do you set `playerMovement ` if you don't use it for something later in the code?

Comment: Moveleft should be True after KEYDOWN event, not False.

Answer (score 2):

I've restructured your main loop to fix the problems. I change the `playerMovement` (velocity) in the event loop now and use it to update the `playerRect` in the main loop with the [`pygame.Rect.move_ip`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip) method.

By the way, you can pass the `playerRect` to `blit` to blit the image at the `topleft` (`x, y`) coords.

```
# The player's velocity. Define it outside of the main loop.
playerMovement = [0, 0]

while True:
    # Handle events.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                playerMovement[0] = 2  # Set the x-velocity to the desired value.
            if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                playerMovement[0] = -2
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                playerMovement[0] = 0  # Stop the player when the button is released.
            if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                playerMovement[0] = 0

    # Game logic.
    playerRect.move_ip(playerMovement)

    # Draw everything.
    display.fill((214, 42, 78))

    tileRect = []
    y = 0
    for row in level:
        x = 0
        for col in row:
            if col == '2':
                display.blit(grass, (x*16, y*16))
            if col == '1':
                display.blit(dirt, (x*16, y*16))
            if col != '0':
                tileRect.append(pygame.Rect(x*16,y*16,16,16))
            x += 1
        y += 1

    display.blit(player, playerRect)
    windowSurface.blit(pygame.transform.scale(display, windowSize), (0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, black, playerRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :D